# angular [WDS] disconnected and page reload every 1 min

Tags: node.js, angular, wds

My Angular v.8 project used to run successfully but suddenly it console an error [WDS] Disconnected! and then reload it happens every min.
any ideas?

I need solution to stop my project from reloading every 1 min.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular cli - how to disable auto reload when ng serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566999/angular-cli-how-to-disable-auto-reload-when-ng-serve)